# Tracking location and direction without GPS?

Tags: electrical-engineering, measurements, sensors

How can I track a device's location (x,y,z coordinates) as well as the direction the device is facing (north, south, up, down, etc.)?

Standard accelerometers are not precise enough for very small scale (personal hand-held devices) and tend to drift.

In addition, satellite GPS is not available in the location where this device would be used.

Comment: GPS provides position.  GPS doesn't provide orientation.  FYI

Comment: What's the scale of the environment? Inertial Nav systems have been around for years. They can be smaller and lighter than ever since they're now using MEMS.

Comment: A compass is a useful device for understanding the direction.

Comment: What is the engineering application?

Comment: Key question - what scale/range/speed do you want. eg does this all fit in a 2m per side cube - or hundreds of metres. Does this move at 1mm/hour or 100 m/s or ...? There are a range of potential solutions but we need to know what the rEAL questiuon is to best suggest them.

Answer (score 3):

There are several way to address your question, on such way is to use a

1. Magnetometer to track North, West, East, South etc
2. Barometric Pressure Sensor to measure up & down (elevation)
3. Accelerometers to track motion/speed

Depending on your application our sensing elements can be added to improve accuracy.

Also take a look a the concept dead reckoning. Algorithm developed using [dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) can address the lack of GPS satellite signal. Dead reckoning is commonly used in automotive navigation application as well as some enterprise handheld applications. I also responded to a similar post on electrical engineering stackexchange, and link is listed below.

---

**References**

- [How can I measure distance traveled in cm without gps?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/180648/how-can-i-measure-distance-travelled-in-cm-without-gps/180659#180659)
- [Dead reckoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning)
- [Barometric Pressure Sensor](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bmp180-barometric-pressure-sensor-hookup-/measuring-weather-and-altitude)
- [High Accuracy, 3D Magnetometer](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=MAG3110)

Comment: Before relying on magnetics for direction bearings, ensure the area where the device will be used does not have anomalous magnetic fields, whether natural or otherwise. [Mag Anomalies] (http://survinat.com/2013/01/magnetic-anomalies-and-anomalous-zones/), [US Mag Anom Maps] (http://mrdata.usgs.gov/magnetic/)